There are infinitely many scalars $c\in F$ such that $\{v_1+cw_1,\ldots,v_n+cw_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.
Suppose $V$ is a vector space over an infinite field $F$. Given $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ be two bases of $V$. To show that there are infinitely many scalars $c\in F$ such that $\{v_1+cw_1,\ldots,v_n+cw_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.
Only thing which I could show is that the collection of such scalar $c$ is nonempty, since $0$ clearly works. But I have no clue to proceed further. Any hint to continue will be appreciated. Thank you.

I suggest:  work this for the case $n=2$ to start.  As a hint:  phrase this as a question about a determinant.

In the base $\{w_1,\dots w_n\}$, calling $M\in M_n(K)$ the matrix of the base $\{v_1,\dots v_n\}$, the matrix relative to $\mathcal B=\{v_1+cw_1,\cdots, v_n+cw_n\}$ is simply $N=M+c\text{Id}$. By definition $\det(N)=p(c)$ where $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $M$, so $N$ is invertibile (or equivalently $\mathcal B$ is a base) for all $c$'s that are not roots of $p$.
This means that one between $\{v_1,\dots v_n\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots w_n\}$ doesn't need to be a base: it's obvious for the first one and it's true for the second one too since we can divide by $c$ and consider the coefficient $\frac 1 c$ for $c\neq 0$.

Just one thing to clarify, in my calculation $\det (N)=(-1)^np(-c)$, where $p(x)=\text{ch}{M}(x):= \det(xI{n \times n}-M)$.

Nice answer. I think $\det N$ is the characteristic polynomial of $-M$. Well that hardly matters since $p(c)$ is an $n$-degree polynomial and has at most $n$ roots. Thus, $\det N$ is non-zero for all but finitely many scalars $c\in F$. No need to mention anything about characteristic polynomial so that that the answer is accessible to more people.
